# Jquery button only works once. Should work more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a random quote generator made with Javascript and Jquery. When the button is clicked, it should display a random quote. This works once, but the button does not work again unless the page is refreshed. The button should work an infinite number of times. Can anyone please help me with this issue?

```js
//quote variables
const quoteOne = '1';
const quoteTwo = '2';
const quoteThree = '3';
const quoteFour = '4';
const quoteFive = '5';
const quoteSix = '6';

//quotes Array
const quotes = [quoteOne, quoteTwo, quoteThree, quoteFour, quoteFive, quoteSix];

//randomize quotes
let randomQuote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
   
$(document).ready(() => {
  //jquery variables
  const $newQuote = $('#new-quote');
  const $text = $('#text');

  //handlers
  $newQuote.on('click', () => {
    $text.text(randomQuote);
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quote-text">
    <span id="text">???</span>
  </div>
  <div class="buttons">
    <button class="button" id="new-quote">New quote</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: You're only picking the random quote once, not every time the button is clicked. Move that code into the click handler.

Comment: *button only works once* - it works every time, just does the same thing every time

Comment: Programming languages are not like spreadsheets. Variables don't hold the expression that was used to assign them and re-evaluate it every time they're used. They just hold the value that the expression returned. So you have to re-execute the assignment for the value to change.

Comment: thank you very much. moving the function into the handler fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The button is working, you just need to regenerate the randomQuote on each button click.

```js
$newQuote.on('click', () => {
    randomQuote = quotes[Math.floor(Math.random() * quotes.length)];
    $text.text(randomQuote);
  })
```